# Closed circuit app on Android

Tags: applications, permissions, privacy, vm

I'd like to know if there is a way to run an android app on a closed circuit minimalist type of android VM on an android device so that I can have a full control of what the app has access to and when it is allowed to run.
I'm asking this because I have to use the facebook messenger app (the mobile browser version of facebook doesn't allow you to use instant messaging anymore) and this app causes a **HUGE power drain**, as well as a big **privacy issue** (that app has access to almost anything on the smartphone)
I know that it is still possible to use the desktop browser version on android but it takes more time to load than the adapted client.
Also if there is another client that I could use to replace messenger while still using their messaging system, that would answer the question.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Marshmallow has finer control over what permissions are allowed.

Comment: I have an LG G3 D855 with Android 5.0 lollipop
I could technically upgrade to Marshmallow but I have installed Kingroot and even after uninstalling it, il tells me that my device may be rooted and that it won't upgrade for that matter.
Is it worth factory resetting my phone to switch to Android M or are the improvements just small bug fixes?

Comment: You should read about the permission changes, which are significant for your case: http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-advantage-new-app-permissions-marshmallow

Comment: Oh, this seems way better than the permission manager app, thanks I'll try to upgrade to android M asap